# Syntax highlighting not working as expected in nano (regex error)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, nano

Lately I've been doing a bit of simple C coding in nano, and the syntax highlighting is behaving strangely. I'm not super experienced with the command line, so I might be unwittingly doing something wrong. Hopefully someone here can give me a suggestion.

I downloaded the sample C syntax file that came with nano 2.0.6 (since that's the version which came preinstalled) and am using it with one line commented out. Some of it works as expected, but some important parts, like the following line, don't:

```
color green "\<(float|double|bool|char|int|short|long|sizeof|enum|void|static|const|struct|union|typedef|extern|(un)?signed|inline)\>"
```

What I've determined is that although it will not highlight int in green, it will highlight  in green. Or , , etc. That is, the angle brackets which appear to be escaped (representing word boundaries) are behaving as though they are not escaped. I confirmed this by removing the backslashes and relaunching nano. The behavior didn't change.

Any syntax definition which uses escaped angle brackets in the regex gives me the same issue. Googling for this issue has proven fruitless, so I'm at a loss. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're on OS X, as that's the version Apple's continued to use. (Licensing reasons, I assume.) Apple's libc doesn't seem to support `\<` and `\>`, nor does it support `\b`. Replacing them with `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` respectively should work.

See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#posix

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with your libc regex implementation or perhaps because you're using a rather old version of nano, which may be statically linked to an older libc. You could try updating to a new version, if possible.

You could also try using `\b` to replace both `\<` and `\>`. It *should* be equivalent.